# Pipeline | in bash usage?

Tags: bash

I am learning BASH, my problem is the following.

I'm decompressing a file using `tar -zxvf`, this returns a (what I think) is a list type `ls -l` from the folder it has been extracted.
What I want to do is take the first object of it using `head -1`.

I can do this, but to keep my code clean I would like to do it using pipeline.

This works:

```
filename_2=$(tar zxvf ${filename}) 
echo "${filename_2}" | head -1
```

This doesn't (it returns an empty string):

```
filename_2=$(tar zxvf ${filename}) | head -1
echo "${filename_2}"
```

Am I understanding the pipeline concept wrong? I thought that it simply took the input from the last function as input of the last one, if so, why do I need to do it in two separate lines?

Thanks

Comment: Your line `filename_2=$(tar zxvf ${filename}) | head -1` pipes the output of `filename_2=$(tar zxvf ${filename})` to `head -1`, but `filename_2=$(tar zxvf ${filename})` doesn't produce an output. When you did `filename_2=$(tar zxvf ${filename})` as in your first example, you'd notice you only got a prompt back and you had to `echo "${filename_2}"...` to get the output. It takes the output of `tar` and puts it into the variable `filename_2`. So it's output is empty. You probably just want `tar zxvf ${filename} | head -1` and forget the `echo "${filename_2}"`.

Comment: No worries. You really just have to break it down into pieces and think about it that way, which is what's nice about the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the variable at all. Pass the output of `tar` directly to `head`.

```
tar zxvf "$filename" | head -1
```

If you then wanted to save that result in a variable you'd write:

```
filename_2=$(tar zxvf "$filename" | head -1)
echo "$filename_2"
```